# Unable to print S3 data in java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I want to read txt file from S3 bucket and populate it in list of objects. 
For now I'm simply trying to print the data read from S3 bucket but instead it's printing empty.

I tried changing many thing but unable to understand what am I missing?
txt file contains: 
1217
1338
1216
1337
1215
1336
1211
1332
I know its number but doesn't matter I want it as string, it should at least print the data before I parse.
Here's the code sample:

```
    S3ObjectInputStream inputStream = s3Object.getObjectContent();
    byte[] bytes = inputStream.readAllBytes();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println("postal codes:");
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line); //no output getting here.
            list.add(line);
        }
        System.out.println(list.size());
    }
```

Comment: I don't know S3 very well but `S3ObjectInputStream` indicates this is meant to be some sort of serialized data. If the data only represents numbers I'd say that shouldn't work - no serialized objects in the file = no data returned.

Comment: how is `s3Object` created?

Comment: s3Object is simply created by amazonS3.getObject(bucketName,FileName);        
I printed bytes length and it giving me 13923 as value, so I think it should also give the actual value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got the solution by my self.
As InputStreamReader is not able to read from S3ObjectInputStream directly, it's easy to use

> InputStreamResource

So did changed my code to following:

```
InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(s3Object.getObjectContent());

    System.out.println("postal codes:");
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream()))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your question’s code, you have the line `byte[] bytes = inputStream.readAllBytes();`, which does exactly what it says, reading all bytes from the input stream. So it comes at no surprise, that the subsequent attempt to read from the same input stream via `InputStreamReader` reads no data, you have already read all bytes. Your “solution” works, because it doesn’t contain that statement anymore. Of course, putting the `InputStream` into an `InputStreamResource` and getting *the same* input stream back from it, has no influence on the code.